# Find word to the left of character(s) regex

Tags: regex

I have the following text:

```
table.UID ID,
table.first_name FirstName,
table.last_name LastName,
```

I would like to use regex to get the first word from the left of a comma and line-break `,\r\n` up to the first space   character. Does anyone know how I can achieve this? This is what it should find:

**ID**
**FirstName**
**LastName**

This is as far as I have gotten `,\r\n(.*?)[\s]`. The issue with this is that it's selecting the characters to the right instead of the left. Please forgive my lack of regex knowledge.

Comment: Are you looking for `(?m)\S+(?=,\r?$)`? See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LGOOQW/2).

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
(?m)\S+(?=,\r?$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LGOOQW/2).

*Details*:

- `(?m)` - multiline mode on
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars
- `(?=,\r?$)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with a `,`, an optional CR char and end of line position.